# Setting up an SQLlite database in R from a csv file that cannot read into memory

Tags: r, sqlite

I have a large *.csv file that I would like to query using `SQLlite` and `dplyr` verbs in R. How can I connect it to SQLlite without reading it into memory?

I can parse it in as I also have an `fst` version but the whole file is 120GB.

Comment: I would recommend using function ```readr::read_csv_chunked()```. You can even transform the data before sending it to the database.

Comment: SQLite won't load the file into memory. `dplyr` will, because it. can only work with in-memory data. If you *don't* want to load the data in memory, use SQL queries as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that SQLite is a good fit for something that large.  SQLite stores the entire database in a single file and you might be better off using a client server database that distributes it across multiple files.

In any case, ignoring the above this will create an empty SQLite database `mydb.sqlite` and read `myfile.csv` into a table `mytable` that it creates in that database.  It will do so without the data ever going through R -- it works entirely on the SQLite side.  You might need additional arguments depending on the file.  You will get a warning but can ignore it.  Test it out on a subset of rows first.  Then delete the database created and try with the entire file if that worked.

```
library(sqldf)

read.csv.sql("myfile.csv", sql = c("attach 'mydb.sqlite' as new", 
          "create table new.mytable as select * from file"))

# test that it is there
sqldf("select * from mytable limit 3", dbname = "mydb.sqlite")
```

Alternately SQLite has a command line shell that could be used to do that.  See https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: Thank you that was super quick! I've loaded it up. You're right, it's not fast to load. Quick question. Where does the database "live" and does it live without me saving it with some sort of write function?

Comment: The database is in the `mydb.sqlite` file in the current directory (or in whatever path you use).  You don't have to do anything nother than the statements shown.